# How control layout in i18n web application?

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, internationalization

Suppose there is fmt:message tag appears in div tag with fixed width:

```
<div style="width=10px"/>
    <fmt:message key="some.code" />
</div>
```

Depends on code the actual message can be less or greater than 10px, and text "came out" of div or make it bigger and affect layout.

Is there a way to insert line terminates into the message or control actual width or div?

Comment: Do you have to keep the width fixed?